# Inheritance with Virtual function

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, virtual-functions

Consider a base class having a virtual function and parent class inherits this base class and implements that function. Say if a child class inheriting parent class has a function with same definition , does it override?

Also, I am trying to implement features in such  a way that base class has a virtual function and parent class inherits base class but does not implement it but the child class inheriting from parent class implements it.
Is this allowed?

Comment: Yes and yes .......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the short answer see the comment from  πάντα ῥεῖ.

> Consider a base class having a virtual function and parent class inherits this base class and implements that function. Say if a child class inheriting parent class has a function with same definition , does it override?

I am a bit confused about your usage of base, parent and child, but if I just take it literally (apart from "same definition" which I interpret as "same signature" and I assume you mean pure virtual in the base) and translate it to code it looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

struct base { virtual void foo() = 0;    };

struct parent : base { void foo() { cout << "parent" << endl; } };

struct child : parent { void foo() { cout << "child" << endl; } };

int main() {
    child c;
    c.foo();  // prints "child"
}
```

In the subclass a method does not have to be declared as `virtual` again to make it `virtual`. I am a pretty much a pre-C++11 guy, but I know that there is a [`override`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) identifier that can help to make sure a method is actually overriding something. You would use it like this:

```
struct child : parent { 
    void foo() override { cout << "child" << endl; } 
};
```

If `child::foo` does not override this will cause a compiler error.

> Also, I am trying to implement features in such a way that base class has a virtual function and parent class inherits base class but does not implement it but the child class inheriting from parent class implements it. Is this allowed?

Again I interpret "virtual" as "pure virtual" (otherwise I dont understand the question):

```
struct base { virtual void foo() = 0;    };

struct parent : base { };

struct child : parent { void foo() { cout << "child" << endl; } };

int main() {
    child c;
    c.foo();     // prints "child"
    // parent p; // not OK
}
```

This is allowed, as `child` inherits all its base classes methods. The only thing to consider is that if a class inherits from an abstract class and does not implement all abstract (= pure virtual) methods it is also an abstract class (ie you cannot create objects of this class).

**PS**: I hope I understood the question correctly and I dont get flamed for answering such a basic question. Please note that you can check such things by yourself easily with a bit of code. Inheritance issues are rarely compiler dependant and it helps to play around to understand what is going on. Also `override` is a quite cool new feature that leaves no doubt whether a method is actually overriding.

**PPS**: As a sidenote, imho the child - parent analogy is one of the worst. In reality a child becomes a parent once it inherits its genes to a child. On the other hand (public) inheritance models a "is-a" relationship. Does it make sense to say "every child is-a parent"? Obviously no! In this sense it would make even more sense to call the base class "child" that inherits to the "parent" (sounds strange, no?) because every parent is-a child. Ergo, either way the analogy is flawed. I wont start a fight against windmills, but I can try to spread the idea. My recommendation is to not call them "child" / "parent" at all but just stick to "base" and "subclass" which is much less confusing.